# How do I print the number of lines in which a string appears 2 or more times using unix grep and regular expressions?

Tags: unix, grep

I need to search one .txt file and this is only if a word appears twice in one line. So if I had the phrase: "I fed my cat today and my cat was happy" it would return 1, but only if that word appeared twice in that same line. I need a line count of this for the entire file. I am using the program putty to do this in unix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
grep -e "cat.*cat" input | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grep "cat.*cat" input_file | wc -l
```

Explanation:

- `grep`: [what is grep?](http://kb.iu.edu/data/afiy.html)
- `"cat.*cat"`: in this case, the pattern to search for: literally `cat`, followed by `.*`, where the period `.`  means "match any character", and it's quantified by star `*` (0 or more), so together they mean "matching any number of characters", followed by literally another `cat`
- `input_file` next argument to `grep`, in order to "save a cat" (don't worry about the "saving the cat" part, silly nerdy joke =p)
- `|` is the pipe command in unix, it takes the `stdout` from grep and feeds it into the `stdin` of the next program, which is...
- `wc -l` - invoke the "word count" program and use the "line" option to count number of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Find and count in one `awk` command

```
awk '/cat.*cat/ {a++} END {print a}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

```
cat.*cat
```

You may have to add anchors for word boundaries (tool dependent syntax) if you just want to match whole words.